# VScode Exception occur: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: visual-studio-code, exception, vscode-code-runner

When I try to run any c++ program in vs code an exception occur and do not run the program

```
Oops, something went wrong.  Please report this bug with the details below.   
Report on GitHub: https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine/issues/new
-----------------------------------------------------------------------       
Last 101 Keys:
 c d Space " c : \ U s e r s \ U S E R 
\ D o c u m e n t s \ p r o g r a m m i n g \ " Space ; Space i f Space ( $ ? 
) Space { Space g + + Space c o d e 2 . c p p Space - o Space c o d e 2 Space 
} Space ; Space i f Space ( $ ? ) Space { Space . \ c o d e 2 Space } Enter   


Exception:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The value must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the console's buffer size in that dimension.
Parameter name: left
Actual value was -1.
   at System.Console.SetCursorPosition(Int32 left, Int32 top)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Internal.VirtualTerminal.set_CursorLeft(Int32 value)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.ReallyRender(RenderData renderData, String defaultColor)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.ForceRender()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.Insert(Char c)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.SelfInsert(Nullable`1 key, Object arg)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.ProcessOneKey(ConsoleKeyInfo key, Dictionary`2 dispatchTable, Boolean ignoreIfNoAction, Object arg)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.InputLoop()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.ReadLine(Runspace runspace, EngineIntrinsics engineIntrinsics)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

By using manual command in terminal , I can run my c++ program.

I can find some issues in vscode github repository about this problem but can not understand any solution

Comment: After reloading the code-runner extension, the exception does not show me. Is it problem for code-runner extension ?

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue.  Uninstalled and reinstalled Code-Runner, and it looks to be ok now.

Comment: i also did it, but still sometimes i face it.

Comment: What is the Code-Runner? The IDE?

Comment: @Sam - it looks to be a vs code extension.  Admittedly, I have zero memory of this.