# Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException when running any C++ code in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

```
Oops, something went wrong.  Please report this bug with the details below.
Report on GitHub: https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine/issues/new        
-----------------------------------------------------------------------  
Last 100 Keys:
 Space & Space ' c : Ctrl+Alt+\ U s e r s Ctrl+Alt+\ . v s c o d e Ctrl+Alt+\ e x t e n s i o n s Ctrl+Alt+\ m s - v s c o 
d e . c p p t o o l s - 1 . 1 8 . 5 - w i n 3 2 - x 6 4 Ctrl+Alt+\ d e b 
u g A d a p t e r s Ctrl+Alt+\ b i n Ctrl+Alt+\ W i n d o w s

Exception:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The value must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the console's buffer size in that dimension.    
Parameter name: left
Actual value was -1.
   at System.Console.SetCursorPosition(Int32 left, Int32 top)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Internal.VirtualTerminal.set_CursorLeft(Int32 
value)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.ReallyRender(RenderData renderData, String defaultColor)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.ForceRender()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.Insert(Char c)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.SelfInsert(Nullable`1 key, Object arg)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.ProcessOneKey(ConsoleKeyInfo key, Dictionary`2 dispatchTable, Boolean ignoreIfNoAction, Object arg)  
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.InputLoop()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.ReadLine(Runspace runspace, 
EngineIntrinsics engineIntrinsics)
```

The error is followed, after a few seconds, by a Windows pop-up saying

> "Unable to start debugging. Unable to establish a connection to GDB. Debug output may contain more information."

---

Attempted solutions:

- As the only answer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75206547/vscode-exception-occur-system-argumentoutofrangeexception) suggest to reinstall the Code-Runner, I reinstalled both VSCode and MSYS64, but the issue persist. Is the Code-Runner something else?
- As per [this Experts Exchange post](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29140606/Powershell-Script-Copy-and-Paste.html), I installed PSReadLine, leading only to the console outputting `Cannot load PSReadline module` followed by the already mentioned Windows pop-up.
- In [this Github post](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1536), user @SeeminglyScience says that "`Clear-Host` will fix it", yet I know not where to write that command.

Comment: Has this installation of VS code ever worked with C++?

Comment: @user4581301 it was working this morning